# Unable to update jenkins using yum in rhel8

Tags: linux, jenkins, configuration, yum, rhel

I have installed the jenkins as per their documentation. And then when i try to update jenkins its giving these wierd errors. The ports 443 and 80 are open. Can any assist on this issues.

Logs:

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo
[jenkins]
name=Jenkins-stable
baseurl=http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable
gpgcheck=1
```

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/yum.conf                                                                                           
[main]
gpgcheck=1
installonly_limit=3
clean_requirements_on_remove=True
best=True
skip_if_unavailable=False
ip_resolve=4
[root@mcdefrapl008 ~]#
```

```
[root@server ~]# yum update                                                                                                
Jenkins-stable                                                                                     0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'jenkins':
  - Curl error (56): Failure when receiving data from the peer for http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/repodata/repomd.xml [Recv fa
ilure: Connection reset by peer]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'jenkins': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors
 were tried
```

```
[root@server ~]# curl http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/repodata/repomd.xml -v
*   Trying 151.101.2.133...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to pkg.jenkins.io (151.101.2.133) port 80 (#0)
> GET /redhat-stable/repodata/repomd.xml HTTP/1.1
> Host: pkg.jenkins.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
[root@mcdefrapl008 ~]#
```

Just to mention, when i open the url in the browser it is redirecting to https.

Answer (score 0):

`yum` do not redirect to `https` automatically. So set in your repo `https` and try again.

```
[jenkins]
name=Jenkins-stable
baseurl=https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable
gpgcheck=1
```

Comment: This seems working but the updates of jenkins not happening with this.

```[root@server ~]# jenkins --version
2.339```

```[root@server ~]# yum update jenkins
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:01 ago on Fri 06 May 2022 07:49:03 AM UTC.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
[root@server ~]#```

There are updates available for jenkins

Comment: @Nikhilesh, according to `yum` and jenkins repo there are no updates.